# Is every right adjoint of a surjective functor fully faithful?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $F\colon C\rightarrow D$ a functor, which is surjective and $G$ a right adjoint of $F$.
Is $G$ always fully faithful? What if $C,D$ are abelian and $F$ is additive?

I know that it is always faithful. But must it be full?

Comment: What is a surjective functor? You mean essentially surjective?

Comment: For every Object $A$ in $D$, there is an object $B$ in $C$, such that $T(B)=A$. Even stronger than essentially surjective, but I think it doesn't change anything on the question.

Comment: The right adjoint is faithful (resp. fully faithful) if and only if the adjunction counit is a natural epimorphism (resp. natural isomorphism). I don't see any reason for this to be the case with your hypotheses.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: Faithfulness is clear. This follows from the triangle identities and the fact that $T$ is surjective.

Answer (score 5):

Let $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Vect}$ be the free vector space functor. (Choose any base field $k$ you like.) It is essentially surjective on objects, and with some cardinality tricks you can arrange for it to be actually surjective, if you want. But its right adjoint is only faithful, not full.

Along similar lines, the functor $F : \mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Vect}$ that sends an abelian group $A$ to the tensor product $A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} k$ is essentially surjective on objects (and additive), but the right adjoint is not always full. (Take $k = \mathbb{R}$, for example.)